# Написание эффективного кода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, объекты, проектирование

При формировании данных возникла проблема. Необходимо данные поместить в объект, точнее в ассоциативный массив, содержащийся в объекте. Это можно сделать с помощью `.serializeArray()` и передать в объект, где есть предусмотренный метод **set...**, такой способ я и привел в примере кода ниже. Но мне кажется это способ не очень хороший и правильный, и хочется, чтобы было профессионально сделано.

**Код для первого скрина:**

```
<div id="tab1" >
        <div class="row"> 
          <div class="col-xs-10"><h3>Описание</h3></div>
          <div class="col-xs-2"><button type="button" id="step1" class="next btn btn-success pull-right">Далее</button></div>
        </div>
        <form id="descrip">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="titleT">Название теста:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titleT" placeholder="Название теста" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="descripT">Описание теста:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="descripT" placeholder="Описание теста"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tarAidience">Выберите целивую аудиторию:</label>
          <select name="tarAidience" class="form-control">
            <option value="teach">Преподаватели</option>
            <option value="stud">Студенты/абитуриенты</option>
            <option value="all">Для всех</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="answer">Проверять ответы</label>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

**Код для второго скрина:**

```
<div class="">
          <form id="Questions">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="question">Вопрос:</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="question" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите вопрос" />
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-10">
              <label>Выбирете тип вопроса:</label>
              // Тут типы вопросов. Убрал т.к. и так много текста
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="pull-right btn btn-success" id="addBtn"><span class="addimg"></span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
```

**JS-код, предполагаемый объект**

```
// Объект тест. Все данные и их обработка происходят здесь.
    function test() {
    // Вспомагательная переменная заменяющая this
    var self = this;

    // Основная информация о тесте, такая как
    // Название теста, описание, орентация на аудиторию, 
    // Флаг проверкии ответов. 
    var aboutTest = {
        // Название теста
        'title': '',
        // Описание теста
        'description': '',
        // Орентация теста(препод., студ./абитур.)
        'testFor' : '',
        // Флаг проверки ответов(true/false)
        'checkAnsw' : '',        
    };

    // Данные о вопросах, включают в себя 
    // О самом вопросе, типе ответа, вариантах ответа
    // Правильных ответах, если установлен соответ. флаг 
    // В массиве *aboutTest['checkAnsw']
    var Qustion = {
        // ИД вопроса/его номер
        'id': '',
        // Сам вопрос
        'itselfQ' : '',

        // Тип вопроса
        // Один ответ = type1, несколько = type2 , пронумеровать = type3,
        // В свободной форме = type4, сопастовление = type5
        'typeAnswer' : '',
        // Массив вариантов ответа. Загружаются после добавления вопроса.
        'VarAnswer' : { // ИД вопроса/его номер
        'id': '',
        // Сам вопрос
        'itselfQ' : '', },

        // Массив правильных ответов. Загружаются после добавления вопроса.
        'Answer' : {// ИД вопроса/его номер
        'id': '',
        // Сам вопрос
        'itselfQ' : '', },
    }

    //******************************************
    // Проверка и фильтрация введенных данных*
    function checkerr() {

    }

    // Установка инфор. о тесте. Принимает данные
    // Ввиде ассоциативного массива 
    self.setAboutTest = function (dataAbout) {

    }

    // Установка вопроса.Принимает данные
    // Ввиде ассоциативного массива 
    self.setQustion = function(dataQustion) {

    }

    self.print = function() {
        console.log(aboutTest);
        console.log(Qustion);
    }
}
```

[image: Данный на описание, идут в question]
[image: Данные на описание, идут в about]

Comment: а где `js` код?

Comment: Добавил. там только два зачатка под массивы и все. 
я думаю опять мой вопрос останется без ответа:D

Comment: Я не понял: в чем именно заключается вопрос?

Comment: Как правильно вытащить данные из `input` и добавить в объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с `.serializeArray()` мне кажется будет не удобным при использовании, с использованием jQuery, можешь сделать что-то подобное:

```
var forms = {};

function getFormArray($form) {
    // соберет объет вида {name: value, name: value}
    var formData = {};
    $form.find(':input').each(function() {
         formData[this.name] = this.value;  
    })
    return formData;
}

$('form :input').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);    
    forms[$this.parents('form').attr("id")] = getFormArray($this);
})
```

в `forms` у тебя будут храниться все данные по разным формам, если захочешь получить данные, обращаешься `forms.Questions.name`

Comment: А почему Вы  используете знак `$` в переменных к примеру здесь `$form`?

Comment: это удобно, знаком `$` помечаем `jQuery` объект, получается, когда вы видите `$form` вы сразу понимаете, что это не значение чего-то, а `jQuery` объект и знаете что с ним можно делать :)